# Is it better to use an axe or sword in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently started playing Minecraft, and I have been trying out some of the netherite tools, and I noticed that the axe does more damage, but it's slower than the sword. Does the axe get better in the long run, or why is the sword faster, and can it outclass the axe? Is there a reason why I see a lot of popular Minecraft YouTubers like Dream use axes in these places? It does seem unusual. I also saw a video by Technoblade saying that it would be more useful to use a sword, but I'm not exactly sure. Does the math add up, or is it a scam, and do people need to switch weapons? What weapon should I use?

Comment: this is often a matter of opinion, and also depends on the situation

Comment: Why do that when the DPS of the sword is higher where in any situation you would be better off with a sword because it would do the same damage in the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An axe does 2 more damage than a sword would. If a diamond sword does 7 damage, then a diamond axe would do 9 damage. To get the most damage, you have to wait a bit more for the cooldown to finish. Using an axe is sometimes quicker because you need to hit an enemy once, and it might just die right then and there, whereas a sword would take 2 or 3 hits. Speedrunners use axes because it does more damage, but in a lets-play, it isn't a good idea because, for each hit, it takes away two durability.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why would the speedrunners do it, if their goal is to kill the dragon? It would be much easier with a sword, because then you could land much more damage over the time you have. Or would they just use beds?

Comment: Speedrunners usually use beds, because they take a lot of damage away from the dragon, and they are quick to use, so use axes in the overworld and nether, and beds in the end.

Comment: Speedrunners use axes because that's simultaneously a tool to chop wood and to kill mobs. The difference in DPS is so small it doesn't make up for the time spent obtaining resources and crafting the sword.

Answer (score 7):

When unenchanted, axe does 2 more damage and loses twice as much durability.
When enchanted, sword is far better because of enchantments available (sweeping edge, fire aspect, knockback, looting)

Answer (score 3):

Using both is best. Keep an axe in your hand to charge it. Then, when the enemy comes, do a crit with an axe. It would do 15 damage. Then, switch to your sword. The sword has higher DPS then the axe, so finish off your enemy(ies) with the sword.

Answer (score 0):

Swords are better because if you are all geared up and deciding which tool is the best, an enchanted Netherite Axe or Sword, Swords do more knockback. You might think that would give an advantage for the Axe to strike, but the Sword can get Fire Aspect, and the Axe can't, so overall the Sword is a better weapon.

Answer (score -2):

I think the axe is the best weapon in Minecraft because diamond sword has 7 damage but the axe has 9 damage.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, we prefer if new answers introduce new information or reasoning than what has already been covered. What you've said is already covered by [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/386352/242480).